# Access VBA: Compare two listboxes

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, compare

i have two Listboxes in Access VBA.
I want to compare These two listboxes and want to delete Items from the second listbox, if the same Item isn't listed at the first listbox.

For example:
Listbox 1 Values: "Item 1", "Item 3"
Listbox 2 Values: "Item 1", "Item 2", Item 3"

Now i want a function that compares These two Listboxes and deletes "Item 2" from the Listbox 2, because it isn't listed in the Listbox 1.

I tried some code, but the only Thing i've got is this one:

```
If BR_TeamReport.ListCount > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To BR_TeamReport.ListCount - 1
        For y = 0 To BR_Team.ListCount - 1
            If BR_TeamReport.ItemData(i) = BR_Team.ItemData(y) Then
                MsgBox ("Don't Delete")
            Else
                MsgBox ("Delete")
            End If
        Next y
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: I am assuming that Listbox 1 also has other value like "Item 4" so each listbox contains different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
If BR_TeamReport.ListCount > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To BR_TeamReport.ListCount - 1
        FoundItem = False
        For y = 0 To BR_Team.ListCount - 1
            If BR_TeamReport.ItemData(i) = BR_Team.ItemData(y) Then
                FoundItem = True
            End If
        Next y
        If Not FoundItem Then
            ' Delete item as it was not found in the first listbox
            BR_Team.RemoveItem (y)
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

I think this will achieve what you want.

Comment: Please flag my answer as being the answer and up arrow it.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry for that, did it a few moments ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not clear 2nd list box, and then repopulate with first one?

```
For i = 0 To LstBox2.ListCount - 1
   LstBox2.RemoveItem(i)
next i 

For i = 0 TO LstBox1.ListCount - 1
   lstBox2.AddItem LstBox1.ItemData(i)
Next i
```